# Adding Data in Firebase Database

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am migrating to Firebase to help me retrieve my data. My question is how can I format my Firebase Database data like the JSON below. How can I specify objects like the JSON below?

```
[
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR.LUTAAYA HUZAIFAH IDRIS",
    "HealthCentreName": "Mulago",
    "Specialisation": "Dentist",
    "Information": "am genious",
    "photo": "huzaifah.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "8:00am - 3:00pm",
    "PhoneNumber": "0704594180",
    "Email": "huxaiphaeridris@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR. G. WABULEMBO",
    "HealthCentreName": "Kibuli",
    "Specialisation": "Opthalmologist",
    "Information": " is a consultant Opthalmologist with over 25 years experience in Canada and Uganda.",
    "photo": "wabulembo.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "8:00am - 12:00pm",
    "PhoneNumber": "0756478923",
    "Email": "wabulembo@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR. BUKIRWA JAUHARAH",
    "HealthCentreName": "Kibuli",
    "Specialisation": "Urologist",
    "Information": "Shes a Urologist , she has an experience of 7 years in Kibuli Hospital , and she studied in the United States Of America University",
    "photo": "jauharah.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "10:00am - 4:00pm",
    "PhoneNumber": "0706081457",
    "Email": "bukijauha@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR. R. SEKITOLEKO",
    "HealthCentreName": "Nakasero Hospital",
    "Specialisation": "General Physician",
    "Information": " is consultant physician with over 33 years of experience in Berlin and Hamburg (Germany) and Mulago Hospital (Uganda). He also practised as a consultant with WHO (2001-2003).",
    "photo": "sekitoleko.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "12:00am - 7:00pm",
    "PhoneNumber": "0765633667",
    "Email": "sekitoleko@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR. A. MAKHOBA ",
    "HealthCentreName": "Nakasero Hospital",
    "Specialisation": "Cardiologist",
    "Information": "is a consultant cardiologist,. He has practised for more than 20 years in Illinois and Wisconsin (USA) and for over two years in Uganda, at the Uganda Heart Institute and Nakasero Hospital.",
    "photo": "makhoba.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "8:00am- 4:00pm",
    "PhoneNumber": "0765453636",
    "Email": "makhoba@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR.Sako Banabus",
    "HealthCentreName": "Nakasero Hospital",
    "Specialisation": "Dentist",
    "Information": null,
    "photo": "kamanzi.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "7:00pm - 3:00am",
    "PhoneNumber": "0754369696",
    "Email": "sw@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "DoctorsName": "DR. KAMANZI ABUBAKAR",
    "HealthCentreName": "Mengo Hosiptal",
    "Specialisation": "Neurosurgeon",
    "Information": "Hes a Neurosurgeon, he has an experience of 20 years in Mengo Hospital , he studied in the Carlifornia University",
    "photo": "kamanzi.jpg",
    "WorkingHours": "7:00pm - 3:00am",
    "PhoneNumber": "07003014850",
    "Email": "kamanziabubakar75@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write pretty much any JSON you'd like directly to Firebase. For ease of retrieval though, you'd need to figure out some sort of schema. I'd recommend something like the following:

```
doctors
  <docotrId>
    - doctorId
    - doctorName
    - specialisation
    - information
    - photo
    - phone
    - email
    - @healthCenter
healthCenters
  <healthCenterId>
    - centerId
    - name
    - @doctors[]
specialisationDoctors
  <specialisationName>
    <doctorId>
```

The first thing you need to do is map your data to this schema. You can create POJO classes, Maps, or even JSON formatted strings.

Then push your mapped data using `setValue()` on the appropriate nodes. Make sure to read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data) for more information.

You might also want to check out a Firebase object mapper I'm working on called [Firebomb](https://github.com/akhahaha/firebomb-java) (shameless plug). The Android version will be coming soon.

Finally retrieve data by using the appropriate [Firebase event listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data).

Comment: Thanks @ Alan K , but it's still confusing, Can make it more clear and easy

Comment: @Lutaaya not sure if I can make it more clear given how general your question is. What exactly don't you understand? If you're looking for the specific code to write, perhaps you can start by telling me what platform (Android, web, Java server etc) you're trying to implement this in?

Comment: Ok  @Alan , specifically i was talking about Android , i said its confusing because , its difficult for me to retrieve into Android . Am trying to implement that JSON  format I posted in Firebase , so that I retrieve it easily.